# "before each" hook for "sets the aggregator addresses correctly" TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'JsonpcProvider')

Tags: hardhat, test

actual issue looks like that i had faced :(

[image: error]

when i tried running `yarn hardhat test`
it was always error outing like in above image.
I have searched solution but could not find proper solution to it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Edit `"ethers": "^5.7.2"`
   into your `package.json`

[image: package.json]

2. Delete `node_module`
3. `yarn install` or `npm install`

And your issue done ✅.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do by

1. `yarn remove ethers`
2. `yarn add ethers@5.7.2`

Answer (score 0):

this was really really helpful.
and fortunately this solution  works so  perfectly which you have suggested on second no.
i.e.(You can also do by

yarn remove ethers
yarn add ethers@5.7.2)